# How to download .apk file by DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

How to download apk file through Download Manager:
I tried through this code:

```
public class UpdateCheckerService extends Service {    

    UpdateChecker update_checker;
    DownloadManager downloadManager;
    String Download_path="http://www.xxxxx.com/mobile_api/xxxxxx.apk";
    SharedPreferences preferenceManager;
    String Download_ID = "100";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public void onCreate()
    {
        System.out.println("SERVICE ************ CREATED");
    }
    public void onStart(Intent intent1, int start_id)
    {
        System.out.println("Service started");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
         registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, intentFilter);
         System.out.println("Service started");

        if(isNetworkAvailable())
        {               
            if(true)
            {
                System.out.println("Update AVAAILLL:");
                preferenceManager = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                 downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                 Environment
                  .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                  .mkdirs();

                   Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(Download_path);

                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);

                    long download_id = downloadManager.enqueue(request.setTitle("Downloading...")
                            .setDescription("xxxx").setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive").setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                                    "xxxxx.apk"));

                    Editor PrefEdit = preferenceManager.edit();
                    PrefEdit.putLong(Download_ID, download_id);
                    PrefEdit.commit();
            }
        }   
    }
    public void onDestroy()
    { }
```

When i am  going to install the .apk its telling parse error. 
and in logcat its is telling unable to read the manifest file.
Actually the size of .apk file is 400kb but after downloading it showing 40kb.

Please suggest where i am wrong..

Answer (score 0):

there's no way to do this. That's for security- otherwise you'd have every website stealth installing apps on people. You can download the apk and then use a file manager to install it, but you can't download and install in one action through a browser.

Comment: I am not installing through the browser. i just want to download the .apk file from my server to the mobile SD card.